# How to loop through 2 arrays in powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am fetching the disks along with the vm names to which those disk are attached, then i want save disk name & VM name in a variable as a json.  when i run the below code i am not getting the desired output, can someone help me with the correct code.

```
$disks=Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName MFA-RG | where {$_.ManagedBy -ne $null} | select name, managedby
$vmlist=foreach ($name in $disks){
$name.ManagedBy.Split('/')[8]
}
$vmname=foreach ($name in $disks){
$name.Name
}
$vmname=@{}
for($i=0; $i -lt $disks.count; $i++){
$vmname[$i] = $vmlist[$i] }
$vmname | ConvertTo-Json
```

I am expecting output like

```
{
"disk 1" : "VM1",
"disk 2" : "VM2"
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?  If you run just segments of the code, one at time. What results are yo getting? Meaning, running $disks, what is returned, then running $vmlist, what gets returned? ... and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to accomplishing what you want. You need to make a few edits though:

```
$disks=Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName MFA-RG | where {$_.ManagedBy -ne $null} | select name, managedby
$vmlist=foreach ($name in $disks){
$name.ManagedBy.Split('/')[8]
}
$vmname=foreach ($name in $disks){
$name.Name
}
$HashOutput=[ordered]@{}
for($i=0; $i -lt $disks.count; $i++){
$HashOutput[$vmname[$i]] = $vmlist[$i] }
$HashOutput| ConvertTo-Json
```

You initialized a new hashtable by running `$vnname = @{}`. This erased everything you had previously stored in `$vmname`. You can just initialize a new hashtable and use the indexed values of `$vmname` as your keys.

You must be cautious in this approach as coded because if the number of disks is 1, then accessing `$vmname[0]` and `$vmlist[0]` will result in just the first characters of those respective strings. Those variables will be type `[string]` rather than `[array]`. I would recommend coding for that condition.

**Explanation:**

`[ordered]@{}` signals PowerShell to create a new hashtable object with ordered keys. This means the key/value pairs will output in the order in which they were added to the hash table.
`$HashOutput[$vmname[$i]]` evaluates `$i` as the current integer value stored in the variable. `$vmname` will typically be an array type in this case, which means its values are indexed. Since `$HashOutput` is a hash table, you can add a new key/value pair using the format `$HashOutput["<key>"] = "<value>"`. In the first iteration of the final loop, `$i` will be 0. Therefore, `$vmname[0]` will be the first element in that array. That element will become the first key added to the hash table. `$vmlist[0]` will be the corresponding value added to that key.